# How can I make a custom object support jQuery change() etc

Tags: jquery

I want to create a new type of composite HTML input. Roughly like this

```
function create_node ()
{
    let node = document.createElement ('span');
    let a    = document.createElement ('input');
    let b    = document.createElement ('input');

    node.appendChild (a);
    node.appendChild (b);

    node.value = '';

    $(a) .change (function () { /* update node.value */ });
    $(b) .change (function () { /* update node.value */ });

    return node;
}
```

I want to be able to write jQuery code like this:

```
let foo = create_node ();

$(foo).change (function () { /* use foo.value */ });
```

What do I have to do in `create_thing` which will make `$(foo).change(...)` work properly, as in, its callback will be invoked (with the correct `this` context) whenever `a` or `b` is changed?

Comment: Are you asking about custom events?: https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that because the `input` nodes already have a `change` event, that event bubbles up through parent nodes by default, so you don't have to do anything.

If the internal nodes don't already have a `change` event, you can do things like this

```
$(internal_node) .click (function () {
    // ...
    $(parent_node) .change ();
});
```

And you can suppress the default change events like this

```
$(internal_node) .click (function (e) {
    e .preventDefault ();
    e .stopPropagation ();
});
```